# Does anyone know how to calculate Authenticode File hash in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, hash, powershell-core, authenticode

I'm looking for a way to calculate the [Authenticode SHA1,SHA256 hashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/select-types-of-rules-to-create#more-information-about-hashes) of a file inside PowerShell. The file is unsigned.

`Get-Filehash` outputs the flat hash which is not what I'm looking for.

ConfigCI built-in module can calculate both Authenticode and Page hashes of a file but I don't want to use them since they provide a lot more details and are time consuming to run.

Module's dll is located here:
`"C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\Microsoft.C99be4d25#\0d6b77335b3aaf092de7496ce37c34bc\Microsoft.ConfigCI.Commands.ni.dll"`

.NET or C# code is also okay, I can use either and run them in PowerShell

Comment: If you can't find an existing working library, this looks like a non-trivial task, because you have to parse the PE file and skip various data blocks that are not included in the authenticode hash. An alternative approach could be to actually try and sign a temporary copy of the file using the Win API and then read the authenticode hash using the API as well. There might be an API that lets you sign a buffer, so you don't even have to create a temp file.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on your use case? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @zett42 I'm creating a feature for my PowerShell module that allows me to select a WDAC xml policy and a folder then shows me which files would be allowed/blocked by the policy if it was deployed on the system and the programs in that folder were to run, something like simulating WDAC deployment. The xml file includes data about signed and unsigned files. I've finished the signed file calculations but struggling with unsigned files which I'd thought would be easier. I need the calculation to happen fairly quickly.

Comment: The authenticode related documentation mentions the Win API function `ImageGetDigestStream`, which is supposed to give us the relevant blocks of a PE file that should be hashed. I've gave it a try, but it doesn't seem to output the correct hash. Maybe I'm doing something wrong though. This is what I have so far: https://gist.github.com/zett42/e2bc15d92f6f38352633ad10796787b2 -- you may want to experiment with the `digestLevel` flags.

Comment: @zett42 thank you, i tried to fix it but still couldn't get it to output the correct hash. I was thinking maybe i can try a brute force method where i give the code the hash i'm looking which i know for a fact that it's the correct one and then it will loop through all possible settings to find the setting that produces the correct hash, but not sure how to implement that. So i ended up using the built-in cmdlet for now: https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/main/WDACConfig/Resources2.ps1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell [get-applockerfileinformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/applocker/get-applockerfileinformation?view=windowsserver2022-ps) shows the authenticode hash

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to do this:

Here is the **C# code**:
https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/main/WDACConfig/WDACConfig%20Module%20Files/C%23/AuthenticodeHashCalc.cs

and here is the **PowerShell code**:
https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/main/WDACConfig/WDACConfig%20Module%20Files/Core/Get-CiFileHashes.psm1

**Documentation**:
https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Get-CiFileHashes

It uses `Wintrust.dll` and it calculates correct Authenticode and first page hashes of files.